# the status of the switch button does not change when refreshing the page in next js

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

Can anyone help with this problem? I'm creating a switch button for a configuration page. when I try to switch, the status has changed from active to maintenance and when I try to save there is a successful alert response, but when I try to refresh the page, the switch button becomes active again.

[Before refresh][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDYQp.png

if you look above that before refreshing, after refresh that page. it will be like this

[After refresh[2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJkiB.png

the status becomes active again. how do I make sure that when refreshing the page the status that has been changed remains on and when changing it back, the status that has been changed when refreshing matches what was changed in next js?

Here's the code

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { WebConfigurationType, WebConfigType } from '@/type/web'
import { getData, postData, putData } from '@/utility/fetch'
import { showMessage } from '@/components/alerts/showMessage';

const STATUS_COLORS = {
    active: 'green',
    maintenance: 'red',
};

const STATUS_TEXT = {
    active: 'Aktif',
    maintenance: '(Maintenance)',
};

const CheckboxSwitch = ({ label, name, checked, onChange }: any) => {
    const labelColor = checked ? STATUS_COLORS.maintenance : STATUS_COLORS.active;

    return (
        <div className="input-banner mb-5">
            <div className="mb-2 flex justify-between gap-4">
                <div className="flex gap-2">
                    <div className="label-banner style={black}">{label}</div>
                    <div className="label-banner" style={{ color: labelColor }}>
                        {checked ? STATUS_TEXT.maintenance : STATUS_TEXT.active}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <label className="relative h-6 w-12">
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="custom_switch peer absolute z-10 h-full w-full cursor-pointer opacity-0"
                        id={`custom_switch_checkbox_${name}`}
                        checked={checked}
                        onChange={onChange}
                        name={name}
                    />
                    <span className={`block h-full rounded-full bg-[#ebedf2] before:absolute before:bottom-1 before:left-1 before:h-4 before:w-4 before:rounded-full before:bg-white before:transition-all before:duration-300 peer-checked:bg-primary peer-checked:before:left-7 dark:bg-dark dark:before:bg-white-dark dark:peer-checked:before:bg-white`}></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

function WebConfig() {

    const router = useRouter()
    const [webConfig, setWebConfig] = useState<WebConfigType>()
    const [config, setConfig] = useState<WebConfigurationType[]>([])
    const [checkStatus, setCheckStatus] = useState(config.reduce((item: any, index: any) => {
        item[item?.name] = item?.is_maintenance
        return item
    }, {}))
    // const initialStatus = {
    //     Beranda: webConfig?.Beranda || false,
    //     Profil: webConfig?.Profil || false,
    //     Template: webConfig?.Template || false,
    //     Pekerjaan: webConfig?.Pekerjaan || false,
    //     Blog: webConfig?.Blog || false,
    //     Bantuan: webConfig?.Bantuan || false        
    // }
    // const [status, setStatus] = useState<any>(initialStatus)

    useEffect(() => {
        const getDataWeb = async () => {
            try {
                const {data} = await getData('/page-configuration')
                setConfig(data.page_configuration)                
            } catch (error: any) {
                return error
            }
        }
        getDataWeb()
    },[])


    const handleChangeBox = (name: string) => {
        setCheckStatus({...checkStatus, [name]: !checkStatus[name]})
        // setStatus((prev: any) => ({
        //     ...prev,
        //     [name]: !prev[name]
        // }))
        
    }

    console.log(checkStatus)

    const generateDialog = async () => {
        
        try {
            await putData('/page-configuration', checkStatus)
            showMessage('Berhasil', 'success')
        } catch (error) {
            showMessage('Gagal', 'error')
        }
    }


    const handleMultiplyCheck = async (ev: React.FormEvent) => {
        ev.preventDefault()
        generateDialog()
    }


    return (
        <>
            <div className='h-full w-full p-4'>
                <div className='w-full h-full bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md border border-slate-200 p-3'>
                    <div className='w-full px-4 py-3 flex justify-between items-center mb-9'>
                        <div>
                            <h3 className='font-semibold text-3xl'>Web Configuration</h3>
                        </div>
                        {/* <button className='bg-[#376DDB] border border-[#2a5bbc] text-white font-semibold whitespace-nowrap px-5 py-2 rounded-md text-base flex items-center gap-3'
                        onClick={() => router.push('./web-config/input')}
                        >
                            <span>+</span>
                            <span>Tambah Data</span>
                        </button> */}
                    </div>
                    <div className='w-full p-3 flex flex-col gap-4'>
                        {config.map((item: any, index: any) => (
                            <CheckboxSwitch 
                                label={item?.name} 
                                checked={checkStatus[item?.name]} 
                                onChange={() => handleChangeBox(item?.name)}/>
                        ))}
                        {/* <CheckboxSwitch label='Beranda' name='Beranda' checked={status.Beranda} onChange={handleChangeBox}/>
                        <CheckboxSwitch label='Profil' name='Profil' checked={status.Profil} onChange={handleChangeBox}/>
                        <CheckboxSwitch label='Template' name='Template' checked={status.Template} onChange={handleChangeBox}/>
                        <CheckboxSwitch label='Pekerjaan' name='Pekerjaan' checked={status.Pekerjaan} onChange={handleChangeBox}/>
                        <CheckboxSwitch label='Blog' name='Blog' checked={status.Blog} onChange={handleChangeBox}/>
                        <CheckboxSwitch label='Bantuan' name='Bantuan' checked={status.Bantuan} onChange={handleChangeBox}/> */}
                        <button 
                            onClick={handleMultiplyCheck}
                            className='p-2 rounded-md bg-blue-400 text-white font-semibold'
                        >Simpan</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default WebConfig
```

I connected it with this json schema :

{
"id": "d9cbf36e-bb51-11ee-a740-00155db75f50",
"name": "Beranda",
"code": "home",
"position": 1,
"is_maintenance": false
}

Comment: Aren't you supposed to make a server call to update the data when toggle the switch ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part at the beginning of your code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { WebConfigurationType, WebConfigType } from '@/type/web'
import { getData, postData, putData } from '@/utility/fetch'
import { showMessage } from '@/components/alerts/showMessage';
```

With this code:

```
const React = require('react');
const { useEffect, useState } = require('react');
const { useRouter } = require('next/router');
const { WebConfigurationType, WebConfigType } = require('@/type/web');
const { getData, postData, putData } = require('@/utility/fetch');
const { showMessage } = require('@/components/alerts/showMessage');
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).